# Why matrix needs be positive definite in order to compute pseudo-inverse of it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found the following statement in this open [book](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf)(given that the matrix $\mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{B}$ is invertable):

> The matrix $(\mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{B})^{−1}\mathbf{B}^T$ is also called the pseudo-inverse of $\mathbf{B}$, which can be computed for non-square matrices $\mathbf{B}$. It only requires that $\mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{B}$ is positive definite, which is the case if $\mathbf{B}$ is full rank.

Provided that the author earlier mentioned that $\mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{B}$ is invertible, I don't understand why the author added another requirement for positive definite of $\mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{B}$, isn't that invertible enough?

Comment: A (real) matrix $X$ such that there is a real matrix $B$ such that $X=B^TB$ will always be symmetric and positive semidefinite (symmetric is obvious, positive semidefinite is because $x^T(B^TB)x=(Bx)^T(Bx)\ge0$ ). In short, the following are equivalent: 1) $B^TB$ invertible; 2) $B^TB$ positive definite; 3) $\dim\ker B=0$. Idem for complex matrices, if we put $B^HB$ and Hermitianity instead.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio with that, it seems likely that the author refers to two different matrices while using the same letter $\mathbf{B}$. One is full rank, the other is any matrix in the general case.

Comment: I don't see anything peculiar with the passage you have cited, and I don't understand if it agrees or disagrees with the point you are raising.